# Windows 10 priotize program in bandwidth usage over windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, bandwidth, priority

there are many questions on different forums asking whether one could turn off automatic Windows updates etc.
But I *want* my Windows to automatically download Updates etc.
*What I don't want* is these getting in the way with my 'main usage'.
So:

**Is there a way to let Windows detect or tell the Windows OS    when there is a program that wants all the bandwidth possible
e.g. when downloading big game( file)s
?**

So that the OS updates stop while the other application is downloading.

Comment: This is handled by Activity Hours on Windows 10.  Windows will update when your NOT using the machine.

Comment: That actual download of Windows 10 updates do not interfere with other downloads, email or web work I am doing. I agree that once downloaded, install will happen in off hours. Windows update downloads seem to be able to co-exist with my other work. Apple IOS updates chew up my bandwidth on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update is very good at not getting in your way when you are using the computer.
In Windows 10, I have never even noticed it using the network while I'm on the computer.

If this is not your case, you may limit its use of the network connection.

**Windows Settings**

You will find it in
*Settings > Windows Update > Delivery Optimisation > Advanced options*:

---

[image]

---

**Group Policy**

Open the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) and position to
*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >
Delivery Optimisation*.

You will find here two policies that can be used for limiting.

The most important is
"Set Business Hours to Limit Background Download Bandwidth"
for limiting hours and bandwidth.

You may also set
"Set Business Hours to Limit Foreground Download Bandwidth",
although it will limit Windows Update when you click the Update Now button,
which may not be helpful.

---

[image]